# Select statement joining 2 tables, searching by date, and status

Tags: mysql, sql

OK I think I have messed up somewhere but maybe someone can spot my error, because I have little clue of what I am doing.

I have 2 Tables Players and RegionPlayer (see bottom for structure)

I am trying to find when a none of the players on a region have been seen in a while.  Players can be on vacation which gives then 58 days, else its only 8 days.
If none of the players on a region have been seen in that time, I want the sql search to return the regionID, as well as the most recent person on that region who was seen.

Now I think that way to do this is to get 2 results from each region, each providing me the most recent player seen who was on vacation, and who was not on vacation.

But while, I thought this would give me that, it doesn't seem to.

```
SELECT RegionPlayer.Regionid, Players.key, Players.Name, Players.Seen, Players.Vacation 
FROM RegionPlayer 
JOIN Players 
ON Players.Key = RegionPlayer.Playerid 
where ( RegionPlayer.Status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY RegionPlayer.Regionid DESC, Players.Vacation DESC
ORDER BY  Players.Seen DESC
```

Then I am going to need to be able to tell who has not been seen in a while, this should give me that.
Now I know I can link both queries together, but I have no idea how, it has been many years since I last had to put this much effort into sql statements.

```
Select Players.key FROM Players
WHERE
(( Players.Vacation != 1 ) AND  
( Players.Seen <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 8 DAY   ) ))
OR
(( Players.Vacation != 0 ) AND  
( Players.Seen <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 58 DAY   ) ))
```

Is There a better way of doing this, I sort of remember things like views, and store procedures, and functions, would one or more of them be better?

Table Structure.
Please forgive, the names, of the tables and some of the structure, This is an example of why deciding things late at night after 1/2 a bottle of wine is a bad idea.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Players` (
`key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Vacation` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `Seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RegionPlayer` (
`Key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Playerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Regionid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `Status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
)
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to have both the vacated and the active player last seen for each region, if you only really want the last seen of each region. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put up an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c93/1).

The query that answers your basic requirement, which seems to be: list all regions that have no active player seen in the last 8 days and no vacated player seen in the last 58 days, giving also the data of the last seen player in that region:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (
  SELECT rp.Regionid, p.Key, p.Name, p.Vacation, p.Seen
  FROM RegionPlayer rp
  JOIN Players      p  ON p.Key = rp.Playerid 
  WHERE rp.Status = 1
  GROUP BY rp.Regionid
  ORDER BY p.Seen DESC
) r
WHERE ((r.Vacation != 1) AND (r.Seen <= (NOW()-INTERVAL  8 DAY)))
   OR ((r.Vacation != 0) AND (r.Seen <= (NOW()-INTERVAL 58 DAY)));
```

I desumed from your SQL that only RegionPlayer rows with a Status of 1 should be considered.

On the SQLFiddle I've create a bit of regions with different combinations, and this query does its job.

As to your first SQL statement. You say it doesn't work as expected, but to me it seems to do it... the last seen active player and last seen vacated player for each region. The sorting may not make it very readable, but it does do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT RegionPlayer.Regionid, m.key, m.Name, m.Seen, m.Vacation 
FROM RegionPlayer 
JOIN (Select * as key FROM Players
WHERE
(( Players.Vacation != 1 ) AND  
( Players.Seen <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 8 DAY   ) ))
OR
(( Players.Vacation != 0 ) AND  
( Players.Seen <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 58 DAY   ) ))) m
ON m.Key = RegionPlayer.Playerid 
where ( RegionPlayer.Status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY RegionPlayer.Regionid DESC, m.Vacation DESC
ORDER BY  m.Seen DESC
```